# redux component is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

The `Count` component is not receiving changes in state for some reason.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore.js';
import { Root } from './containers/Root/index.jsx';

render(
  <Root store={configureStore()} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Root:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { App } from '../App/index.jsx';

export const Root = (
  props
) => {
  const { store } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
Root.propTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

App:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Count from '../../components/Count/index.jsx';
import { Buttons } from '../../components/Buttons/index.jsx';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Count />
      <Buttons />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Count:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Count extends Component{
  render(){
    const { store } = this.context;
    const count = store.getState();

    return (
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    )
  }
};
Count.contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Buttons:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { dec, inc } from '../../actions/incrementDecrement';

const ButtonsList = ({
  count,
  decHandler,
  incHandler
}) => (
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() => decHandler(count)}
    >
      -
    </button>
    <button
      onClick={() => incHandler(count)}
    >
      +
    </button>
  </div>
);
ButtonsList.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  incHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  decHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    count: state,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    decHandler: (count) => {
      dispatch(dec(count));
    },
    incHandler: (count) => {
      dispatch(inc(count));
    }
  };
};

export const Buttons = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ButtonsList);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved by adding `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` to the `Counter` component:

```
export default class Count extends Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context;
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
      this.forceUpdate()
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render(){
    const { store } = this.context;
    const count = store.getState()

    return (
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    )
  }
};
```